# Camera not follow my 3d character during animation Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, camera

I have a character with one animation. the animation is running. So during the animation start, my character will run one position to other position, but my camera doesnt follow the character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a script controlling the position of the camera or is it just parented to your player object?

If the camera is parented to the player object, it'll follow it everywhere.

However, it'll follow the root of the player object, regardless of the animation currently playing. If during the animation, the player steps forward, its root won't change. The animation of an object has no effects on its position.

You should make your player move through code, not through animation. You shouldn't have any problem then.

Comment: thats it , I tried to connect the root to the camera and its working well. Thanks